# Transform a star's carbon and oxygen into elemental hydrogen

Tags: elements

Forgive me if this a really dumb Question, and yesterday Star Trek: Deep Space 9 suggested a terraforming specialist might transform a star's carbon and oxygen into elemental hydrogen, no details of how or why being given.

Ignoring the logistics, is that not chemically an impossible mission?

Comment: Well, that would be a weird idea, to put it mildly, as stars are literally made of hydrogen. Even white dwarfs have hydrogen in atmospheres.

Comment: @Mithoron Quite. That was my fear, exactly.

Comment: I had higher opinion about Star Trek until now. It is a very dumb idea. Chemically impossible. Using nuclear processes of breaking C and O nuclei, theoretically possible, but technologically **very demanding**, using particle accelerators. Energetically would need  many orders more energy than classical chemical ways. It would be like a fussion power plant going in reverse mode, but even worse.

Comment: @Poutnik Again, quite. That was my fear.

Answer (score 1):

It is an impossible mission, because the usual Carbon nucleus is made of 6 protons and 6 neutrons. And its mass is a little bit less than 6 times the mass of one free proton, plus 6 times the mass of one free neutron. For lack of mass, the splitting of the carbon nucleus into separated protons and neutrons is impossible.

Comment: Maurice, that sounds wholly  reasonable but why did you go that far? My problem is that you did not just dismiss the whole idea out of hand… which suggests it is not wholly unreasonable.

Comment: I don't understand the mass argument - a proton is a proton. Once you separate them, they'll necessarily have the correct mass. The reason carbon is less than the sum of the free masses is E=mc^2

Comment: A free proton has not the same mass when included in a nucleus. Of course, the difference is due to the formula E = mc^2. It means that to remove one proton from a nuclues, this energy must be provided to the nucleus. And this energy is rather huge. This is why a proton cannot be removed from a C nucleus. No experiment can give this huge amount of energy to the proton.

Answer (score 0):

Chemically, it's definitely impossible; hydrogen is another element than carbon or oxygen, and chemical reactions don't change elements into other types. You'd need [nuclear fission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fission) for that (because hydrogen is smaller than the source elements) and a *lot* of energy (think [Large Hadron Collider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Hadron_Collider) - note that that works on the scale of a few atoms, not an entire star).

Comment: And yet as we speak carbon-14 is cycling into nitrogen-14. The scenario is far-fetched but if one were to take the proton and electron being moved around here and liberally (somehow) fuse it into hydrogen, it might pass muster. And there's plenty of similar wiggle room for other beta decaying chains as well as alpha decay.

Comment: Thanks, Glorfindel.

@Todd Minehardt what is that '(somehow) fuse it into hydrogen, it might pass muster'? That looks like a useful Answer and what does it really explain?

Comment: @ToddMinehardt - but a nucleus finding that converting one of the protons into a neutron, or vice versa, is a very different thing than the nucleus deciding it is better to completely fall apart into a bunch of protons. Both 14C and 14N are more stable than being separated into protons+neutrons, its just that 14N is more stable than 14C.

Comment: @JonCuster I stand edified. I'm not entirely in my comfort zone here and advise the OP to heed Jon's comment.

Comment: Are you sure they were not talking about making some C, O, N etc to terraform a planet with too much H.  Setup a super fusion reactor and come back in 30 years!!